# Using Assembly in SSAS Named Calculation

Tags: c#, ssas, assemblies, bids

I am creating my first cube using SQL Server 2008 R2, and Visual Studio BIDS 2008.  I created a small class in C# to handle divide by zero errors. (I plan to use this for creating the various metric calculations my company uses.  I chose to use a method for capturing divide by zero errors as proof of concept before devoting too much time.)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MyFirstCube
{
  public class Mathmatics
  {
        public float GenericDivision (int Numerator, int Divisor)
        {
              if (Divisor == 0)
                    return 0;
              else
                    return Numerator / Divisor;
        }
    }
}
```

I compiled the .DLL and added a reference to the "Assemblies" folder in BIDS.

I then created a Data Source View with a table that has simple integer counts.  DATE_KEY, REGION_CD (Key), MARKET_CD (Key), TOTAL_WIDGETS_SOLD, TOTAL_INVOICES.  I want to add a Named Calculation (TOTAL_WIDGETS_SOLD / TOTAL_INVOICES) = AVERAGE_WIDGETS_PER_INVOICE).

When looking at a daily view, some stores may not have sold widgets, which is why I need to handle divide by zero errors.

I tried adding:

```
Call MyFirstCube.Mathmatics.GenericDivision(TOTAL_WIDGETS_SOLD, TOTAL_INVOICES)
```

per the examples on Microsoft's website.

When I do this I get the error:

```
Deferred prepare could not be completed.
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

First I tried adding the namespace reference:

```
Call MyFirstCube.MyFirstCube.Mathmatics.GenericDivision(TOTAL_WIDGETS_SOLD, TOTAL_INVOICES)
```

Then I tried removing the both namespace and assembly reference:

```
Call Mathmatics.GenericDivision(TOTAL_WIDGETS_SOLD, TOTAL_INVOICES)
```

This yielded the same error.

Then I removed the Class Reference:

```
Call GenericDivision(TOTAL_WIDGETS_SOLD, TOTAL_INVOICES)
```

This gave me the same error, but slightly modified:

```
Deferred prepare could not be completed.
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
Incorrect syntax near 'TOTAL_WIDGETS_SOLD'.
```

I guess my first question is:  Can I use methods from a class library in a named calculation?  If so, can someone help me identify what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of function that you wrote is not suitable for calling it using the `call` syntax. It should be called using function syntax from within MDX like this:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.MyDivision AS
            Mathmatics.GenericDivision([Measures].[Internet Order Count], [Measures].[Customer Count])
SELECT {[Measures].[Internet Order Count], [Measures].[Customer Count], Measures.MyDivision}
       ON COLUMNS
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

The `CALL` syntax is used for functions that return a result set and not a single scalar value. This type of functions cannot be used within MDX, but only in a standalone call.